# Value not being captured and updated from user input

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make it so when the user double clicks an html element it turns into an input field.

At this point I want to capture and update the field to be what the user entered. My current code is producing an empty output. Im thinking its my last line of code causing the issue.

```
dktcell_1.addEventListener('dblclick', function () { //add double click event to cell 1 docket# with anonymous function
  dktcell_1.innerHTML = "<input id=samcel type=text>" // change html element to input field

  dktcell_1.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {//nested keydown event added with e paremeter to access event object properties
    if (e.code === 'Enter') { //check if the user presses "enter"
      dktcell_1.innerHTML = dktcell_1.textContent; //capture value entered and update html element
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: You're missing quotation marks around your HTML attributes, it should be `'<input id="samcel" type="text">'`. But in order to set the `innerHTML` in the second listener you'll need to access the newly created [`input.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#value) (which can be accessed via the `event`) so it would be `dktcell_1.innerHTML = e.target.value;` in the nested listener.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what i was looking for. I totally understand now, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I'm glad it helped

Comment: keypress has been deprecated for a while, try switching to an alternative (e.g keydown)